# itext - How to update a PDF without creating a new PDF?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need to change the value of a field in an existing PDF file.
I am using PdfReader, PdfStamper, and AcroFields and that's working fine. But, in doing so, it is required to create a new PDF and I would like the change to be reflected in the existing PDF itself. If I am setting the destination filename to be the same as the original filename, then my application fails.
I followed the steps located in this site  " https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/faq/how-to-update-a-pdf-without-creating-a-new-pdf "
but I did not succeed
please help.

Comment: You do not mention the version of iText that you are using, but in the old sort-of-free version, it was not possible to change the exisitng file. Keep in mind that you are not writing to a database, in fact you are not writing to anything that was intended to be read/write storage. So it may still not be possible, with or without iText. The method they used to suggest was to write to a different file, then delete or rename the first one, and then the new one to have the same name as the old one.

Comment: Alternatively read the original file into a byte array, initialize the reader from that array, and stamp to the original file name. If something goes wrong, though, all data is lost.

Comment: @arcy you can still do that with iText 7 in the same way as described in the link (byte array). If you say that it doesn't work for you, then you must share your stack trace.

Comment: @arcy and iText still comes in 2 versions: Free and commercial. Can you explain what you mean with sort-of-free?

Comment: @AbderrahimWAGA no need to thank people in comments, use the upvotes instead (small triangles in front of the comments)

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I call it sort-of-free because it was this enormous API for creating docs in HTML, PDF, and something else. There was no unifying model for them I could discern. Its complexity was increased by having to deal with the different target outputs, and then increased further by poor API design, and the documentation that came with the free library was terrible when it existed at all. What you had to do was buy the book, as the authors would repeatedly tell you in forums. So it was sort of free.

Comment: @arcy iText was never an API to create HTML, only to create PDF. A very long time also RTF, but that's maybe a decade ago? API design and documentation has much improved in iText 7, and only last week we launched a brand new developer documentation portal.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse IIRC back when iText allowed RTF creation, there also was a `HtmlWriter` class. But just like the `RtfWriter` class it was discontinued before iText version 5.